# mingw seems to crash python (Anaconda on windows)

Tags: theano

I'm trying to install theano on a windows computer. When I do `import theano` python crashes. I think this is a mingw issue because when I uninstall mingw libpython and try to import theano, I get a theano warning, but python does not crash.

I have tried Anaconda 2.10 and 2.30. I follow the installation up with `conda install mingw libpython`, and then install the latest theano from github. `import theano` still crashes. Any ideas?

Here are the details of the "python.exe has stopped working" message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55678c56
  Fault Module Name:    lazylinker_ext.pyd
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55cdf48e
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 000000000000517f
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    4105
  Additional Information 1: 02b5
  Additional Information 2: 02b5acdc9b8489c31d00cfe986aa8a42
  Additional Information 3: fd67
  Additional Information 4: fd674a72ea70861e63067edee1c9266b
```

Comment: Does Python just quit with no error message?

Comment: I get a "python.exe has stopped working" window pop-up. When I click on "view problem details" I see some things such as ` Fault Module Name: lazylinker_ext.pyd`, and a bunch of other numbers...

Comment: I may not be ale to help myself but those other details will likely be useful for other people to help. Could you update your question with those details?